# A question about derivatives in a particular calculation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am attaching a photo of a calculation from [these notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-152-introduction-to-partial-differential-equations-fall-2011/lecture-notes/MIT18_152F11_lec_12.pdf) below:

[image]

How is $\lim\limits_{r\to 0^+}\frac{\tilde{F}(r+t;x)-\tilde{F}(r-t;x)}{2r}=\partial_t\tilde{F}(t;x)?$

Answer (score 3):

I think there's a typo in the formula: $r-t$ should be $t-r$.

Then it is essentially the definition of the (partial) derivative, written as the limit of the difference quotient (slope of secant line) using for the numerator
$$
F(t+r) - F(t-r) = ( F(t + r) -F(t))  + (F(t) - F(t-r)).
$$
When you divide by $r$ and take the limit as $r \to 0$ you get twice the derivative.